# How do you create a javafilelistflavor object to drop into a JList?

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, jlist, jtree

I have a JTree and JList side by side in my application. When I drag node from the JTree to the JList, the nodes that I have added to `List<File> copies;` are being rejected(`Flavor not supported`) by the method `boolean canImport()` in the transferhandler for my JList.

`System.out.println(Arrays.toString(info.getTransferable().getTransferDataFlavors()));`

returns:

`[javax.activation.ActivationDataFlavor[mimetype=application/x-java-jvm-local-objectref;representationclass=java.io.InputStream]]`

How can I get my JList to accept the drop from my Jtree? I have unsuccessfully tried to create my own dataflavor - this has been commented out in my pasted code.

```
  static class ListTransferHandler extends TransferHandler {

    Logger lgs = null;

    int action;

    public ListTransferHandler(int action) {
        this.action = action;
        lgs = Logger.getLogger("ListTransferHandler Logger");
        lgs.setLevel(ALL);
        lgs.log(Level.INFO, "ListTransferHandler object created");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canImport(TransferHandler.TransferSupport info) {
        //  lgs.log(Level.INFO, "can import called");

        if (!info.isDrop()) {
            return false;
        }

        info.setShowDropLocation(true);

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(info.getTransferable().getTransferDataFlavors()));

        if (!info.isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor)) {
            lgs.log(Level.INFO, "Flavor not supported");
            return false;
        } else {
            lgs.log(Level.INFO, "Flavor supported");
        }

        boolean actionSupported = (action & info.getSourceDropActions()) == action;

        if (!actionSupported) {
            info.setDropAction(action);
            return false;
        }

        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean importData(TransferHandler.TransferSupport support) {

        if (!canImport(support)) {
            return false;
        }

        JList.DropLocation dl = (JList.DropLocation) support.getDropLocation();

        int index = dl.getIndex();

        List<File> fileList;

        try {
            fileList = (List) support.getTransferable().getTransferData(DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor);
        } catch (UnsupportedFlavorException | java.io.IOException e) {
            return false;
        }

        JList list = (JList) support.getComponent();
        DefaultListModel model = (DefaultListModel) list.getModel();
        //insertElementAt(data, index);

        for (File file : fileList) {
            model.addElement(file.getName());
        }

        return true;
    }
}

static class SelectedFileTransferHandler extends TransferHandler {

    //private DataFlavor localObjectFlavor = new DataFlavor( List.class, "Array of items");
    Logger lgs = null;

    public SelectedFileTransferHandler() {
        lgs = Logger.getLogger("SelectedFileTransferHandler Logger");
        lgs.setLevel(ALL);
        //  lgs.log(Level.INFO, "Tranfer object created");

    }

    @Override
    public int getSourceActions(JComponent comp) {
        // lgs.log(Level.INFO, "got source actions");
        return COPY;
    }

    @Override
    public Transferable createTransferable(JComponent comp) {
        //  lgs.log(Level.INFO, "creating tranferable");
        JTree tree = (JTree) comp;
        TreePath[] paths = tree.getSelectionPaths();
        List<File> nodesAsFiles = null;

        if (paths != null) {
            nodesAsFiles = new ArrayList<File>();
            for (TreePath path : paths) {
                nodesAsFiles.add((File) path.getLastPathComponent());
            }

            //File node = (File) paths.getLastPathComponent();
            //  copies.add(node);
            for (File file : nodesAsFiles) {
                System.out.println(file.getPath());
            }

        }
        List<File> defensiveCopyOfNodesAsFiles = null;
        if (nodesAsFiles != null) {
            defensiveCopyOfNodesAsFiles = new ArrayList(nodesAsFiles);
        }
        return new DataHandler(defensiveCopyOfNodesAsFiles, javaJVMLocalObjectMimeType);
        //return new DataHandler(transferedObjects, localObjectFlavor.getMimeType());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised that I can't find a way to make a list of files from my JTree into a `javaFileListFlavor` DataFlavor
to pass to the `canImport`and `importData` methods of my JList's filehandler's. To solve my problem, I have created a custom DataFlavor as shown [here](http://bioportal.weizmann.ac.il/course/prog2/tutorial/uiswing/misc/dnd.html#customFlavor) in the class, `ArrayListTransferHandler.java`.

When `createTransferable()` is called in the JTree's transfer handler - it will pass a `List` object to a class that implements `Transferable`. The latter returns a Transferable of a custom DataFlavor. I haven't finished constructing everything yet but, the code example from the code above (according to my logs) seems to have resolved my issue. The Jlist is now accepting the data I wanted to send it.